# Why does controller scaffolding requires a project that has individual user accounts

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to understand how ASP.NET Core works by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model). It correctly specifies that, if I want to be able to harness the power of controller scaffolding, I have to create a project and specify **Authentication as Individual user accounts**.

When doing this, besides other things, it will generate this class: `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. After several levels of inheritance, it inherits `DbContext`.

If I want to use a DbContext, why am I forced to inherit from IdentityDbContext and cannot simply inherit `DbContext`?

Is it possible to use my own authentication structures and still be able to work with controller scaffolding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gave it a try and you can scaffold the controller but you will need to manually hook a few things first. The [intro to EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) might come handy in understanding how things have to be setup.

- Start with a new MVC project and select *No Authentication* so it doesn't create the IdentityContext.
- Then add to your **project.json** the dependencies needed for both EF Core and scaffolding:

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    //EF Core
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    //Scaffolding
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    ...
    // EF Core
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    //Scaffolding
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  ```
- Create the model class that you want to use, for example:

  ```
  public class Customer
  {
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Email { get; set; }        
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }        
  }
  ```
- Now create a new empty `DBContext` class, for example:

  ```
  public class FooContext: DbContext
  {
      public FooContext(DbContextOptions<FooContext> options) : base(options)
      {
      }
  }
  ```
- Then update `Startup.ConfigureServices` with your context class:

  ```
  services.AddDbContext<FooContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:FooContext:ConnectionString"]));
  ```
- You also need a connection string in your appsettings.json. If starting a new project, you can add one using localdb:

  ```
    "Data": {
      "FooContext": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FooContext-d69c2d45-f845-4069-92ed-2486567146cb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      }
    }
  ```
- When using localdb, you can create the database by adding an initial migration and updating the db. Run these commands from the project root:

  ```
  dotnet ef migrations add initial
  dotnet ef database update
  ```

Make sure you **rebuild your project** after these steps before using the scaffolding options.

- You will then be able to right click the Controllers folder, select *Add -> Controller* and use the "MVC Controller with Views using Entity Framework" option. After you select your model and context classes, scaffolding will generate everything for you.
- You can also avoid manually creating the DBContext class and let scaffolding generate it for you. Just select *new DBContext class* in the same scaffolding dialog and it will create the context class, add the connection string to appsettings.json and update `Startup.ConfigureServices`. (You will still need to create the db, for example adding and running an initial migration)

If you run the project, you will see you can navigate to the generated index page, like `/customers` and see an empty list. **There is one more thing though!**

- The scaffolded edit/create views rely on a partial named **_ValidationScriptsPartial** for adding the unobtrusive validation scripts, and as it doesn't exist in a new project, the edit/create view will throw an error.
- You will need to manually create a new partial view `~/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` with the following contents:

  ```
  <environment names="Development">
      <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
  </environment>
  <environment names="Staging,Production">
      <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
              asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
              asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator">
      </script>
      <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
              asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
              asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive">
      </script>
  </environment>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain step by step.

Comment: No worries, it was an interesting question!